# Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'aportes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked

Tags: mysql

Buenas gente intento hacer un trigger para que inserte el saldo pendiente de pago, por ejemplo, si se hizo un aporte e ingreso estos 3 valores (id_personal,id_concepto_pago,cantidad) (1,3,25) en este caso el concepto de pago no existe para dicha consulta entonces con el query de abajo me llega a traer el valor de NULL, pero si el mando los valores (1,1,25) si me da como resultado un valor, dicho valor lo almaceno en una variable llamada vsaldo para luego unicamente hacer una resta entre ese saldo (vsaldo) y la nueva cantidad ingresada. como podría modificarlo para que funcione, al momento que vaya a buscar valor inserte el valor deseado en vsaldo.

```
delimiter //
create trigger ins_saldo before insert on aportes
for each row
begin
    declare vsaldo decimal(10,2);
    if(select group_concat(saldo) saldo from aportes where id=(select max(id) from aportes where id_personal=new.id_personal and id_concepto_pago=new.id_concepto_pago) is null) then
        select precio_venta from concepto_pago cp join aportes ap on ap.id_concepto_pago=cp.id where ap.id_personal=new.id_personal and ap.id_concepto_pago=new.id_concepto_pago limit 1 into vsaldo;
    else
        select group_concat(saldo) saldo from aportes where id=(select max(id) from aportes where id_personal=new.id_personal and id_concepto_pago=new.id_concepto_pago) into vsaldo;
    end if;
    update aportes set new.saldo = vsaldo-cantidad;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Dejo aqui abajo las tablas para una mejor explicacion:

```
concepto_pago(
id int primary key auto_increment,
descripcion varchar(50)
);

aporte (
id,
id_personal int,
id_concepto_pago int,
cantidad,
constraint fk_aporte_pago foreign key (id_concepto_pago) references concepto_pago (id)
);
```

Gracias, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Checa si la solución de está publicación te sirve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537750/1442-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already

Comment: Cree una solución pero no me funciona al 100%, no hace nada cuando el valor es NULL. puedes ayudarme con esto?

Comment: Cree una solución pero no me funciona al 100%, no hace nada cuando el valor es NULL. puedes ayudarme con esto?

Comment: Puedes establecer dentro de tus case uno para cuándo el valor sea null algo así : `CASE WHEN valor IS NULL......` y en esa condición tal vez construir la lógica que debe procesar

Comment: ya hice eso y no funciona, si uso el mismo query que la condición, para pruebas, puedo hacer un ifnull y funciona muy bien, pero aqui no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

elaboré otro query donde funciona 2/3 ya que no me funciona cuando el valor es NULL. Te muestro:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_saldo BEFORE INSERT ON aportes
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.saldo = (
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (select group_concat(saldo) saldo from aportes where id=(select max(id) from aportes where id_personal=new.id_personal and id_concepto_pago=new.id_concepto_pago)) > 0 THEN
            (select group_concat(saldo) saldo from aportes where id=(select max(id) from aportes where id_personal=new.id_personal and id_concepto_pago=new.id_concepto_pago)) - new.cantidad
         ELSE 
            (select precio_venta from concepto_pago cp join aportes ap on ap.id_concepto_pago=cp.id where ap.id_personal=new.id_personal and ap.id_concepto_pago=new.id_concepto_pago limit 1) - new.cantidad
        END
FROM aportes 
WHERE id_personal = NEW.id_personal and id_concepto_pago = new.id_concepto_pago 
LIMIT 1);
```

cuando trae el saldo anterior es mayor a 0, se ejecuta la sentencia que le coloqué, cuando es 0 también funciona, el detalle es que no funciona cuando es NULL.